# Searchable Dropdown search is not working when i access the id as value inside DropdownMenuItem | Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, search, package

Iam using searchable_dropdown: ^1.1.3 package to search elements in dropdownmenu, when i use district (which give district name) for the value inside DropdownMenuItem it works properly. But the problem is when a user selects district i want the value as districtId. but when i give districtId as value the search is not working. Below is my code.

```
                              Center(
                                child: SearchableDropdown.single(
                                  isExpanded: true,
                                  value: selectedName,
                                  hint: "Select one",
                                  searchHint: "Select one",
                                  // hint: Text('Select Name'),
                                  items: districtList.map(
                                    (list) {
                                      return DropdownMenuItem(
                                        child: Text(list['district']),
                                        value: list['districtId'],
                                      );
                                    },
                                  ).toList(),
                                  onChanged: (value) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      selectedDistrict = value;
                                      print(selectedDistrict );
                                    });
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
```

This is the package https://pub.dev/packages/searchable_dropdown